# Force browser to refresh just 1 file

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, browser

I work on a project where several CSS and JS files are loaded separately onto the page. We use query stings like `.css?1234` to force browsers to refresh a file on load.

I have returned to the project to find that one file that needs to be refreshed is not refreshed. I want to refresh one file at a time using the browser inspect element until I find what fixes the issue. Adding query strings to each individual file is not easy in this particular project.

Is there a way to only refresh a single CSS or JS file using the browser inspect element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the include tag and re-add it.